# Getting friends from depth 2?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible for a Facebook app to get friends of depth 2?

What I mean is the following:

> If user `A` is using the app, and `A` has a friend `B` who is not
>   using the app. Can I get a list of `B` friends (depth 2)?

Is it maybe possible by some kind of specific permission?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible.

Consult this list of permissions to see what is available via the API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/