# Getting mutual friends number FAST?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's say I have a user `A` who is using my facebook app, and `A` has a friend `B` who is not using the app. **Can I get the number of mutual friends between `A` and `B`?**

**EDIT**

Colm, correctly suggested to use `friends.getMutualFriends`, but unfortunately it's VERY VERY SLOW. So I was thinking, is there maybe any FQL code that can do the same but much faster?

I found FQL queries (after searching) like this:

> SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend
>   WHERE uid1=me()) AND uid2 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =
>   friend_id;

but they don't work, and throw the following error:

> Can't lookup all friends of XXXXXXX. Can only lookup for the logged
>   in user (XXXXXXX), or friends of the logged in user with the
>   appropriate permission.

So, what is this `appropriate permission`?

---

This question is based on my previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810911/getting-friends-from-depth-2), but I need just the number of mutual friends, not the list of `B` friends. I couldn't find anything in graph api permissions list :(

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can mutual_friend_count attribute in user table

```
SELECT uid, mutual_friend_count from user where uid=53638897
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Graph API has just added mutual friend support according to their [latest blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/565/) via this type of url: https://graph.facebook.com/me/mutualfriends/FRIEND_ID.

Comment: requires iterating over each friend, and therefore is not viable.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd have to get both lists and diff them in your code if you wanted to use the Graph API. Or you could run a loop that calls `/User_id1/friends/User_id2` and that will return true if User_id1 is friends with User_id2.

If you are ok with using the Rest API, you can use [friends.getMutualFriends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getMutualFriends/).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I tried `friends.getMutualFriends` and although does what I want, it's very very slow. I tried using FQL instead to get mutual friends from some exaples I found in the net but all queries returned this error message `Can't lookup all friends of *****. Can only lookup for the logged in user`. Is it possible to be done faster?

Comment: The issue with the FQL query you're trying to run is that you can only call the `friend` table for users who have authorised your app with basic permissions. The error message your getting means UID2 hasn't given those. So whilst you can give it UIDs to see if one of your users is friends with someone, you can't pull UID2's friends to compare it. 

Does that make sense? Not sure how well I've phrased it.

Comment: yes it absoulute does. Thanks for explaining it to me :)

Do you maybe happen to know another better/faster way to get the mutual friends?

Comment: I can't think of a faster route off the top of my head sorry.