# How to get the posts that a friend reshares using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I faced with the following problem. I would like to know how to get all the posts that has been reshared by my friend using FQL. I use the following query:

```
SELECT post_id, type, source_id, actor_id, target_id, via_id, app_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=<friend_id> AND via_id LIMIT 0,100
```

but unfortunately it returns an empty list. At the same time, when I execute the following query for my account I get the list:

```
SELECT post_id, type, source_id, actor_id, target_id, via_id, app_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND via_id LIMIT 0,100
```

I generated a token for all possible permissions. Could someone, please, point me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you tried for other friend ids? + you have the `read_stream` perms?

Comment: Yes, I've tried for many friends. And as I wrote I added all the permissions to execute query in FQL explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your both queries are correct.

```
SELECT post_id, type, source_id, actor_id, target_id, via_id, app_id 
  FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id=<friend_id> AND via_id 
 LIMIT 0,100
```

It is only that, through the API, [you can't access Users from depth 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810911/getting-friends-from-depth-2). For instance, it is impossible to get your friends' friendlist.

If one of your friends shared one of your friend's post, then you will see one result.
If one of your friends shared a random user's post, then no results.

For privacy reasons, the API only allows to access the information in a quite closed circle of friends.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh.. I was wondering about the question as well for some time..

Using Graph API we can get all the links that I have shared..

```
GET me/links?fields=link
```

Comment: It's also possible to get all the links using fql for myself and I've provided the example of the query. My question is how to get the results not for myself but for one of my friend. The same query returns empty list.

Comment: Well If you can try.. Get {friendsUSERID}/posts it gives all the post made by my friend. So make a batch request to get the userid of all the friends. Then get all their posts then cross compare withe the links you have.. This would be extremely stupid. And As far I think Facebook Guys should really look up a way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT via_id, link_id, caption, url
FROM link 
WHERE owner={user_id}
```

`via_id` will show you the unique identifier of the original link poster. If `via_id`=0 you are the original linkposter.

At least it will work for links.